# Добавить в ssh config коннект с 2мя пользователями

Tags: ssh

Есть сеть серверов. На них стоят разные системы. Коннект к сети идет с помощью конфига:

```
Host network
Hostname %h 
User centos
ForwardAgent yes
```

Как добавить в поле `User` 2х юзеров, например `ubuntu or centos`
Чтобы конфиг автоматически перебирал их при коннекте.

Comment: «перебирать» имена пользователей программа ssh, к счастью, не обучена. если вас не устраивает указание имени пользователя в url при подключении (user@host), можете, к примеру, добавить ещё одну секцию host (подсказка: значение hostname вовсе не обязано совпадать со значением host, и вовсе не обязано быть уникальным)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, к сожалению, так сделать не представляется возможным, т.к. хосты постоянно появляются новые с разными системами, и в ручную мониторить на каком какая система и вписывать их в ssh конфиг - очень утомительно)
Возможно кто-то знает более универсальный вариант.

Comment: *и вручную … вписывать их в ssh конфиг* — так автоматизируйте процесс! вы программист или где? подсказка: см. `$ man -P cat ssh_config | less -pInclude`

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто решается с помощью `bash`. Содержимое скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./script_name.sh host user1 user2 user3 ...

for NAME in "${@:2}"
do
  echo "Try to connect under ${NAME}"
  if ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -q ${NAME}@$1 exit
  then
    echo 'Connected!'
    ssh ${NAME}@$1
    break
  fi
done
```

Использование в вашем случае:

```
./script.sh host.network ubuntu centos
```

Скрипт будет сначала тестировать подключение пользователем `ubuntu` к `host.network`, потом пользователем `centos`, если предыдущая попытка подключиться не удалась и т.д.

UPD: Добавил флаг PreferredAuthentications

Comment: Впринципе такой вариант вполне подходит, можно его даже прописать в стандартный алиас на коннект ssh) Единственное только - проблема в том что если например на сервере нет юзера centos, а мы его перебираем, то в ответ получим
`centos@host's password:`
и попыток коннекта со следующим юзером уже не будет

Comment: @Dofri со стороны клиента можно ограничить способы аутенфикации, обновил скрипт.